# Electron - require is not defined, despite nodeIntegration being true

Tags: javascript, html, electron, require

my problem is - I got a main.js file, and a functions.js file, where I want some of my functions to be. However, whenever I use require in that functions.js file, I get an error, require is not defined.

I've read posts about other people having similar problem, but in their case setting nodeIntegration to true helped. That's what I had from the beginning. I know the problems of this solution, but at the moment I don't need the app to be secure, so I would be fine with this solution, if it worked. It doesn't.

I tried preloading, but I think it's just a "safer" equivalent of nodeIntegration solution. And being an equivalent, it doesn't work either. Can you help me?

My code:

**main.js**

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron')

function createWindow () {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: true,
      preload: 'functions.js'
    }
  })
  win.maximize();
  win.loadFile('index.html');
}

app.on('ready', function() {
  createWindow();
  createOpenDialog();
});
```

**functions.js** (literally, this is all it takes for the code to fail)

```
const electron = require('electron');
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />
</head>
<body style="background: white;">
    <script src="functions.js">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

So, one thing I didn't try was **setting contextIsolation to false**. And least it seems like it, because I was sure I tried it. Anyway, this seems to fix the issue, although I will need to learn what it does exactly. I can do "require" now, and already tested if it works by using ipcRenderer.

Answer (score 1):

Context isolation is a security feature that exists on Electron. Its whole purpose is to separate the preload scripts and Electrons internal apis from your website so it doesn't  have any access it should not have.

From Electron 12 context isolation is off by default .This means that if you need to expose some functionality in your preload scripts you will have to use context bridge

An example from the documentation is this :

### Before context isolation was off

```
window.myAPI = {
  doAThing: () => {}
}
```

### After : context isolation is on

```
const { contextBridge } = require('electron')

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('myAPI', {
  doAThing: () => {}
})
```

You can read more about this feature in the docs :
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/context-isolation

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! I will make sure to check it.